# Calling variable before declaration

Tags: python

For my first project I'm making a number game, the computer guesses a number and the user tells the computer if The guess is greater than, less than, or equal to the number they are thinking. My code is set up like this:

```
guessNumber = 0

def greaterThan():

    guessNumber += 1
    print("Is your number less than, greater than, or equal to ", (100 + (100 / 2 ** guessNumber)))

''' I know my math is wrong here but I'm trying to get the program to work first '''

    lessORgreater = input()

''' I have a function for lessThan() and equalTo() '''

lessORgreater.lower()

 #pretty sure this needs to be fixed because I don't think it's right

If (lessORgreater == "greater"):

    greaterThan()
```

That's basically what I have. It's very similar for the `lessThan()` and `equalTo()` just tells the user the computer won.

The error I'm getting says that

> Local variable 'guess number' referenced before assigned

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def greaterThan():
    global guessNumber
    guessNumber += 1
    ...
```

You can look [here](https://stereochro.me/ideas/global-in-python) to learn more about `global`.